# How to add and validate google captche in dnn page

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have work on dnn 7.1 .I have add the Google catcha in DNN page.
see reference from this site

[code for add captcha in asp.net](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/aspnet)

with the help of this reference i have add the captcha in dnn page. but in the captcha validation is not work. anything write in the text box. not show the error message. and form submit successfully . Any one help me **what can i do for validation**.
code are given below

```
<%--<%@ Register TagPrefix="recaptcha" Namespace="Recaptcha" Assembly="Recaptcha" %>--%>
<%@ Control Language="C#" ClassName="Admin.ContactUs" Inherits="DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.PortalModuleBase" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Configuration" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>

<script runat="server">

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            SendMailTest();
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

</script>

<div class="contactusform-left commonclass lF">
    <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    /* Code for textbox, dropdowm */

</div>
<div class="contactusform-right commonclass lF">


    <div class="contactusform-set-textarea  contactusform-set" style="height:150px;">
        <label class="lF">
            Captcha <span>*</span></label>
            <div style="clear:left;width:100%;height:100px;">


     <recaptcha:RecaptchaControl  ID="recaptcha"  runat="server" PublicKey="6LdCxeYSAAAAAAP-uIGWnsZHeW7rn8rzeeblc5g" 
                                            PrivateKey="6LdCxeYSAAAAAFvnxCiaN_7vkHp-vaVRRYb9yVF" />
                                            <asp:Label Visible=false ID="lblResult" runat="server" />

            </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div class="contactusform-set " style="margin-top:10px;">
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"
            ValidationGroup="ContactUsValidate" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" Style="color: #8D8D8D; cursor: pointer;
            float: right; font-weight: bold; height: 34px; margin-right: 5px; text-transform: uppercase;
            width: 120px;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without sample code it will be very hard to give you a valid answer here, but the most common cause of it would be if you are using a "ValidationGroup" on the button or other controls, but not on the CAPTCHA.

Otherwise, we need to see your specific code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that DotNetNuke provides the Telerik captcha control? You can use it exactly as described here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/captcha/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx but you just need to replace radCaptcha by dnnCaptcha in your code and add these two lines at the beginning of your file:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" Namespace="DotNetNuke.UI.WebControls" Assembly="DotNetNuke" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" Namespace="DotNetNuke.Web.UI.WebControls" Assembly="DotNetNuke.Web" %>
```

Comment: ok sir...but i have use this code already.My main requirement is google captche that is look n feel like google captcha.